# The installation of a Samsung 960 Evo SSD drive on Linux

Tags: upgrade, laptop, ssd, drive

I am new to Linux. I have an old laptop which I use. I got a Samsung 960 Evo SSD drive and would like to install it on my laptop to make it faster. Samsung used to have an installation for Linux but this but no longer works. Can anybody help me with a step by step procedure to install this drive. Thanking you in anticipation. Dooze

Comment: There's no reason why you need a special Linux setup. I have both the 850 Evo and 850 Pro and they just work out of the box.

Comment: Sorry, were you talking about Samsung Magician? You don't need that for the function of the SSD.

Comment: Hi Lewis, when I connected the SSD out of the box to the laptop, it did not even register. I then tried it on  a Win 10 system with magician. Again did not register. I downloaded Minipartician Tool. There it did register. I have now particianed it and now trying to install the new Ubuntu 18.0 on to the drive. Will let you know if it's successful. Thanks for your response.

Comment: According to [this article](https://blog.kylemanna.com/hardware/samsung-840-evo-trim-support-blacklisted-after-firmware-upgrade/), you're probably out of luck—for now. Samsung's firmware for whatever issue is not supported by the Linux kernel.